# Is it possible to obtain the solution to a networked ode system according to the solutions to the subsystems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Given a networked ode system

$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=f(x_i)+\sum_{j=1}^N A_{ij} g(x_i,x_j),\forall i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$

I am wondering whether the solution to this system can be somehow aggregated from the solutions to the subsystems.

Comment: What aggregated means here?

Comment: This works if the subsystems are weakly coupled. An example is celestial mechanics where single planets have Kepler ellipses as solutions, parametrized by the ephemerides. The inter-planetary gravitation gives slow changes to the ephemerides.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Does "weakly coupled" means that $A_ij$ is small, or the network is sparse? Thanks! And could you also give some references

Comment: If possible both, but the small constants are more important. Or generally the smallness of the coupling terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Got it! Could you give some references or simple examples if possible?